# Adding country subdomain to an existing website like www.example.com/uk

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

I have a website www.example.com and I have put a lot of products using woocommerce. And the URL of those products like example.com/cat/samsung/j7

Now I would like to add country subdomain like www.example.com/uk but keeping the other pages to remain the same almost the same content. So the product pages will be like example.com/uk/cat/samsung/j7

how can I achieve this?

Comment: You could create a MultiSite if you'd like one place to log in and manage everything. Or you could maintain a separate install in each site. Duplicating the content has inherent issues I'll assume you are aware of; you can use WP's export tool to export all of the content and then import it onto the other sites, then tweak.

Comment: I'd like one place to log in and manage everything. Can you please tell me a bit more details on this context?